# i can sort the ip address but when union between another table it give me an error

Tags: sql-server

I want to combine between two table which contain IP address, and i can sort it in ascending order and it works. But when i want to combine it, it parse the error like this "ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator".Here is my query

`SELECT IP AS [IP Adress]
FROM Inventory 
UNION ALL
SELECT IP 
FROM Equip
ORDER  BY CAST('/' + IP + '/' AS hierarchyid)`

Comment: show your sample data and the desired output

Comment: But the order by in the first query. If you want to sort it all, wrap it in a cte and that cast type is Interesting for this case

Answer (score 0):

It thinks you want to sort the second subquery which you cannot do with a union. If you want to sort the whole thing then you should wrap it in parenthesis and order by the new column name that you created.

(
     Select IP AS [IP Adress] 
           FROM Inventory 
   UNION ALL 
    SELECT IP FROM Equip 
    )
    ORDER BY CAST('/' + [IP Adress] + '/'  as hierarchyid )

Comment: thanks for replying but can you give the example of the query? I used sql server

Comment: Its ok, i have found out the solution and here it is..                      
SELECT IP
FROM (
SELECT IP
FROM Inventory
UNION ALL
SELECT IP 
FROM Equip
) x
ORDER BY CAST('/' + IP + '/' AS hierarchyid)

Answer (score 0):

Its ok, i have found out the solution and here it is.. SELECT IP FROM ( SELECT IP FROM Inventory UNION ALL SELECT IP FROM Equip ) x ORDER BY CAST('/' + IP + '/' AS hierarchyid)